# While attempting to install Ubuntu as dual boot, screen goes purple then black after clicking on GRUB menu

Tags: dual-boot, system-installation, uninstall

I'm trying to dual boot Ubuntu with Windows 7, but it's not installing.

Initially, I got a black screen with a blinking cursor, then I added `nomodeset`. Now the problem is that at the GRUB menu, after I click <kbd>Enter</kbd>, it shows a purple screen and then a black screen.

I installed Ubuntu a long time ago, and it worked fine at that time. I since uninstalled it for some reason. Now I can't uninstall the file.

Answer (score -1):

To solve this problem I suggest you to follow the following installation procedure:

While installing Ubuntu at the time of choosing the location and type of installation be careful to choose remove all previous Ubuntu installation and then choose free unused contiguous space to install Ubuntu.

**Note:** ***The above process removes Ubuntu and data from Ubuntu partition**.*

---

It should work. If you still have a problem you may follow the following steps to fix the grub issues:

boot from a live cd or live usb and type the following commands:

1. To add boot-repair to the repository:

   ```
   sudo add-apt-repository ppa:yannubuntu/boot-repair
   ```
2. To Update your repository:

   ```
   sudo apt-get update
   ```
3. To install boot-repair:

   ```
   sudo apt-get install -y boot-repair
   ```
4. Once Installation complete run `boot-repair` on terminal by typing the following command or select it by **System->Aministration->Boot Repair**.

   ```
   boot-repair
   ```

You may also follow the detailed instructions here:

http://www.howopensource.com/2012/05/reinstall-recover-grub-from-ubuntu-12-04-live-cd-usb/